How to get Ebay's OAuth 2.0 access token
Good evening.
I need to find the "Codice Fiscale" field of the users that bought my object, to be able to issue my invoices.
I'm not able to get the Oauth Token. Searching the internet I found this library (pretty old!) https://github.com/neilcrookes/oauth2-ebay/tree/master. First of all I had some problem installing it with composer, because of some issues related to the non-stable version, so I installed manually.
This is the code I put together, from different sources.
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use NeilCrookes\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Ebay;

// Settings
$clientId = 'My_ID';
$clientSecret = 'My_Secret';
$redirectUri = 'THIS_SAME_PAGE';


// Crete the provider
$provider = new Ebay([
    'clientId'                => $clientId,
    'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri'             => $redirectUri,
    'sandbox'                 => true,
]);

// if no authcode, redirect to eBay auth page
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();

    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();

    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
    exit;

// Verify the state for CSRF validation
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    try {
        // Get the Token
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]);

        // Show token data
        echo '<h3>Access Token Details</h3>';
        echo 'Access Token: ' . $accessToken->getToken() . "<br>";
        echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $accessToken->getRefreshToken() . "<br>";
        echo 'Expires: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $accessToken->getExpires()) . "<br>";
        echo 'Has Expired: ' . ($accessToken->hasExpired() ? 'expired' : 'not expired') . "<br>";

        // Save token data to session
        $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $accessToken->getToken();
        $_SESSION['refreshToken'] = $accessToken->getRefreshToken();
        $_SESSION['tokenExpires'] = $accessToken->getExpires();
    } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}

When I run it for the first time, I don't have an authentication code, so I'm redirected to the eBay authentication page.
Once I log in with my sandbox user, I get a 400 error message telling me this: "Got a 400 Bad Request status response from Ebay API".
Unfortunately the error message tells me nothing else.
Can anyone figure out where's the problem?
Thank you
MORE INFO
I tried to var_dump some interesting data and I found this:
file: /vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php
protected function parseResponse(ResponseInterface $response) {
        $content = (string) $response->getBody();
       
        var_dump($content);
        ...
}


output:   "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"request is missing a required parameter or malformed."}"

SOLVED
It looks like there was some code missing in the provider declaration.
$provider = new Ebay([
    'clientId'                => $clientId,
    'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri'             => $redirectUri,
    'sandbox'                 => (bool)($environment=="SBX")
],[
    'optionProvider' => new \League\OAuth2\Client\OptionProvider\HttpBasicAuthOptionProvider()
]);

This "optionProvider" setting seems to be the solution.
